# With node.js, express and handlebars, where should I place the front end javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, highcharts

I have followed this tutorial to build a basic express app with handlebars: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-express--net-33367

Now I am doing different pages with different Highcharts; each of them having a specific front-end javascript that must be placed in the head tag.

I am lost with the structure of the app and where these front end scripts should go in my mvc pattern. If they were completely static I am thinking maybe some .js files in my public folder, but then maybe I want to generate them dynamically. For example by linking the display options (colours and stuff) to the user account. Any tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set something like this?

pattern:

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"</script>
    <script src="highcharts.js"</script>
    <script src="{{chart}}"</script>
</head>
```

example of routing:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index',{chart:"myChart1.js"});
});
```

Comment: And then should I save myChart1.js as a static file in the public folder? What about generating js code dynamically with js code?

Comment: I introduced you how to load dynamically js files, which will be interactive, not png.

Comment: What I mean is: how do I change the contents of myChart.js itself based on the user session or the URL?

Comment: Why you cannot add a condition in javascirpt and then return correct url in the router?